# How to prove that a slab is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, polytopes

$$ X := \left\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2\ : 3\le 2x+3y\le 8 \right\} $$

i tried to solve it as:

Let set $X$ is convex for $x_2,y_2\in X$
such that $\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha)x_2$,$\alpha y_1+(1-\alpha)y_2\in X$

Now, $3\le 2x+3y\le 8$
$2{\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha)x_2}+{3{\alpha y_1+(1-\alpha)y_2}}$
implies
${2\alpha x_1+2x_2-2\alpha x_2}+{3\alpha y_1+3y_2-3\alpha y_2}$;
${2\alpha(x_1-x_2)+2x_2}+{3\alpha(y_1-y_2)+3y_2}$

when $\alpha =0$,
$2x_2+3y_2$
and when $\alpha=1$
$2x_1+3y_1$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, make your question clear. Just what are you asking?

Comment: Generally it is easy to apply the definition of convexity directly to sets that are defined by linear inequalities.  Since your set $X$ is defined by a pair of inequalities, $3\le 2x+3y$ and $2x+3y \le 8$, this should be a particularly straightforward approach.

Answer (score 0):

$X$ is a convex because it is the intersection of 2 half-planes

$$\{(x,y)|2x+3y\leq8\} \  \ \text{and} \ \ \{(x,y)|2x+3y\geq3\} $$

and it is known that a half plane is a convex set.

The reason is that a half-plane is the pre-image by a continuous function  of a convex set ([Convex Sets Pre-image](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/944405)); for example, in the first case, the pre-image of $(-\infty,8]$ by the continuous function $(x,y)\rightarrow2x+3y$.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$ X := \left\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2\ : 3\le 2x+3y\le 8 \right\} $$

Let $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, y_1) \in X$.

Let $\mathbf{y}=(x_2, y_2) \in X$.

By definition,
$$
3\le 2x_1+3 y_1\le 8 \tag{1}
$$
$$
3 \le 2x_2 + 3 y_2 \le 8 \tag{2}
$$

Take any convex combination of $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}$, *viz.*
$$
\mathbf{z} = \alpha \mathbf{x} + (1 - \alpha) \mathbf{y},
$$
where $0 \le \alpha \le 1$.

If we define $\mathbf{z} = (\xi, \eta)$, then
$$
\xi = \alpha x_1 + (1 - \alpha) x_2
$$
$$
\eta = \alpha y_1 + (1 - \alpha) y_2
$$

From (1) and (2), we get
$$
3 \alpha \le \alpha (2 x_1 + 3 y_1) \leq 8 \alpha \tag{3}
$$
$$
3 (1-\alpha) \le  (1-\alpha) (2 x_2 + 3 y_2) \leq 8  (1-\alpha) \tag{4}
$$

Adding (3) and (4), we get
$$
3 \leq 2 \xi + 3 \eta \leq 8
$$
which shows that $\mathbf{z} \in X$.

Hence, $X$ is a convex set.